# I've manually copied files from my time machine backup drive and now I cannot delete them from my computer

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, permission

I got a new computer and I didn't want to do a full time machine restore but rather pick and choose what files I was going to copy off of my time machine drive.

So, I went into the directory, found some files I want, and did `cp -Rpv dir /Users/username/dir`

However, With the `-P` it kept the same permissions as the files on the time machine. `chmod -R 777 dir` doesn't work and neither does resetting permissions from within the 'get info' -> 'sharing and permissions' setting.

How can I get the permissions for the directory back to something that will allow me to delete the directory?

Answer (score 3):

I've sorted it out. First, you need to look at the ACLs that got copied along with the files.

```
ls -le /path/to/dir
```

Once you've done that you can see that everything had this:

```
0: group:everyone deny write,delete,append,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

So, what I did was add a new ACL policy to the directory by doing this:

```
chmod -R +a "admin allow read,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity" dir
```

Followed by:

```
sudo rm -rf dir
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for coming back to share your solution. This helps to make the site really useful for others. :)

Answer (score 2):

another option:

```
chmod -R -a "group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown" /path/to/dir
```

This removes the ACL, rather than adding one. Useful if you intend to keep the files and not delete them.